# how to throw boost bad lexical cast exception

Tags: c++, boost, casting

Can anyone please let me know how to throw bad_lexical_cast exception.

For Unit testing mocking I have the following code:

```
if(!Throw)
    return boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(some_value);
else
    throw boost::throw_exception(boost::bad_lexical_cast());
```

But this is giving a compilation error as follows:

```
error: invalid use of ‘void’ throw boost::throw_exception(boost::bad_lexical_cast());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the first `throw`.  `boost::throw_exception` is a function that simply performs on its own.  More specifically, `boost::throw_exception` takes an exception as an argument, and uses a copy of that passed argument to throw an exception.

```
if(!Throw)
    return boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(some_value);
else
    boost::throw_exception(boost::bad_lexical_cast());
```

`boost::throw_exception` is actually part of the [Boost.Exception](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/exception/doc/throw_exception.html) library, which uses C++ in some clever ways to allow you to attach additional information to exceptions while retaining the original exception types.  Take a look at the linked documentation for more information.